# Lists in python using itertools (moving only 2 items, permutations)

Tags: python, list, permutation

I come from C++ as my 1st programming lenguage, Im just getting into python and im looking for a way to switch numbers from a list, in C++ this would be done using pointers moving them around with loops, however this time I need to generate all the permutations of a list A to a list B in Python

List A (the starter list) and list B (the result list)

```
A= 1234
B= 4231
```

The program has to show all the possible combinations in order, by moving only 2 numbers at he same time until the A list  becomes the B list (the following example is simplified to 4 numbers and might not show all the combinations)

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,4,3]
[1,4,2,3]
[4,1,2,3]
[4,2,1,3]
[4,2,3,1]
```

In order to acomplish this, I have found the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module, that contains a lot of functions, but havent been able to implement to many functions so far, the following code kind of does what its needed however it does not move the numbers in pairs nor in order

```
import itertools

from itertools import product, permutations
A = ([1,2,3,4])  
B = ([4,2,3,1])  

print "\n"
print (list(permutations(sorted(B),4)))
```

Im thinking about adding a while ( A != B )  then stop the permutations, i already tried this but im not familiar with pythons syntax, any help about how can i accomplish this would be appreciated

Comment: you have to find all solutions? or just one? Im confused ... your example is only one possible set of moves to lead to a solution

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205573/is-there-a-sequence-of-swaps-that-would-generate-all-possible-permutations) might be useful.

Comment: you are right @JoranBeasley, i was focusing on one way to solve it just to make it however  in the end the objective is to make it show all the possible moves that lead to the solution

Comment: I don't think itertools is going to do what you want.  Are you required to use that?

Comment: I have answered your question about swapping. If your question is actually how to generate the permutation paths, I could answer that but maybe it should be in a separate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you are asking the best way to solve this permutation question - here is a different answer:

Think of all the permutations as a set. `itertools.permutations` generates all those permutations in some order.  That is just what you want if you want to find all or some of those permutations. But that's not what you are looking for.  You are trying to find **paths** through those permutations.  `itertools.permutations` generates all the permutations in **an** order but not necessarily the order you want.  And certainly not **all** the orders: it only generates them once.

So, you could generate all the permutations and consider them as the nodes of a network.  Then you could link nodes whenever they are connected by a single swap, to get a graph. This is called the permutohedron.  Then you could do a search on that graph to find all the loop-free paths from `a` to `b` that you are interested in.  This is certainly possible but it's not really optimal.  Building the whole graph in advance is an unnecessary step since it can easily be generated on demand.

Here is some Python code that does just that: it generates a depth first search over the permutohedron by generating the neighbours for a node when needed.  It doesn't use `itertools` though.

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
b = (4,2,3,1)

def children(current):
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        yield (current[:i] + (current[i+1],current[i]) +
                   current[i+2:])

def dfs(current,path,path_as_set):
    path.append(current)
    path_as_set.add(current)
    if current == b:
        yield path
    else:
        for next_perm in children(current):
            if next_perm in path_as_set:
                continue
            for path in dfs(next_perm,path,path_as_set):
                yield path
    path.pop()
    path_as_set.remove(current)

for path in dfs(a,[],set()):
    print(path)
```

If you are really interested in using `itertools.permutations`, then the object you are trying to study is actually:

```
itertools.permutations(itertools.permutations(a))
```

This generates all possible paths through the set of permutations.  You could work through this rejecting any that don't start at `a` and that contain steps that are not a single swap.  But that is a very bad approach: this list is very long.

Comment: I was trying to understand your code and fed an input of length 4 , the code goes in to a infinite loop (?) .

Comment: infinite is a strong word :-)  It just takes a long time.  How many paths do you think there are?  Bear in mind that there are 24 permutations, and therefore 24! paths of length 24.

Comment: Upon re-reading your comments it seems like you only want to swap **adjacent** characters, not any pair, though that's not clear from the question.  This dramatically reduces the number of possible paths.  I've changed the code (the `children` function) to only do that and it now terminates in reasonable time.

Comment: After using an input and output of 3, I get that there are 6 permutations and in theory according to your last comment, 6! (thats 720)  paths of lenght 6 however im only getting 2 paths of lenght 4 using your code `(1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1) ` and `(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)`

Comment: Example 1; 2 inputs, then nPr = 2 so 2! = 2 paths, only shows 1 path, `(1, 2), (2, 1)`, Example 2; 3 inputs, then nPr = 6, so 6! = 720 paths, only shows 2 paths, `(1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1)` and 
`(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming sorting of the input list is not really required ,

```
from itertools import permutations
A = ([4, 3, 2, 1])
B = ([1,2,4, 3])

def print_combinations(start, target):
    # use list(permutations(sorted(start), len(start))) if sorting of start is really required
    all_perms = list(permutations(start, len(start)))
    if tuple(target) not in all_perms:
        # return empty list if target is not found in all permutations
        return []
    # return all combinations till target(inclusive)
    # using list slicing
    temp = all_perms[: all_perms.index(tuple(target)) + 1]
    return temp


print print_combinations(A, B)
```

Comment: This one looks to be ok however if you place `A = ([1,2,3,4])` and `B = ([4,3,2,1])` you can see that at the second iteration goes from `1243`  to `1324` so its doing it but its not saving the last position and by default not following the rule of moving numbers in pairs (next to each other)

Comment: I don't get you , what to do you mean by not saving the last position ? Are you looking for bubble sort kind of output ?

Comment: i think he wants `sorted(combos,key=edit_distance(combos[0])`

Comment: No i was trying to explain that I wanted all the possible combinations but then i actually went to read the diferrences between permutations and combinations, so please just forget i said something about saving the last position. your answer is right and implements the premutations function as intended

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you are asking. I think you are asking for a pythonic way to swap two elements in a list. In Python it is usual to separate data structures into immutable and mutable.  In this case you could be talking about tuples or lists.

Let's assume you want to swap elements `i` and `j`, with `j` larger.

For immutable tuples the pythonic approach will be to generate a new tuple via slicing like this:

```
next = (current[:i] + current[j:j+1] + current[i+1:j]
                    + current[i:i+1] + current[j+1:])
```

For mutable lists it would be pythonic to do much the same as C++, though it's prettier in Python:

```
list[i],list[j] = list[j],list[i]
```

Alternatively you could be asking about how to solve your permutation question, in which case the answer is that itertools does not really provide much help.  I would advise depth first search.

Answer (score 0):

I guess following is a simpler way, I had nearly same issue (wanted swapped number) in a list (append a copy of list to itself list = list + list and then run :

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
mylist = ['a', 'b']    
list(set(combinations_with_replacement(mylist + mylist, r=2)))
```

results:
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a')]